# Axios how to retrieve the last 3 articles from api

Tags: reactjs, axios

I want to make a get request that returns the top 3 articles in my articles array from an API. I've searched far and wide and can't find anything that solves my problem.

Basically, I want something like this:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await axios.get(`http://localhost:8000/api/articles/${previous_three_articles}/`)
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us more about the API. It all depends on how the API is structured, and how one can go about requesting multiple articles.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the details of the API that you're requesting from. The most naive way to do this would be to just fetch the entire list of articles and manually select only the "top 3" on the client side.

Comment: Maybe you want to handle this on the API side?  If you could pass in parameters like `page`, `size` from the client, your API could do the rest.

Comment: I'm using django with django rest framework

Comment: Ok, but it all depends on how the endpoint is implemented.  Alternatively, like @jared said, get all articles client side, sort them and take top three.

Comment: But assuming I had a list of a million articles, it wouldn't be efficient to load them all just to extract 3

Comment: Right, which is why we are suggesting that you handle it server side.  We can't give implantation suggestion as we don't know implementation details regarding the API.

Comment: No worries, I've figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Limit Offset Pagination. >>> https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

First, I specified the pagination class in my views.py:

```
class Articles(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    # ...
    pagination_class = pagination.LimitOffsetPagination
    queryset = Article.objects.all().order_by('-creation_date')
```

then specified the limit in react:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { data } = await axios.get("http://localhost:8000/api/articles/?limit=3")
    this.setState({
        articles: data.results,
    })
}
```